# warping to all bonfires

Tags: dark-souls

How can I not warp to certain bonfires throughout the game... I may be wrong but do they need to be kindled for you to be able to warp to them or is it not possible to warp to every bonfire in the game?

Comment: I don't understand what the OP means by "each different game" — each game in the Dark Souls series? Only DS1 was out with [its sequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Souls_II) at the time the question was asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the [Fextralife wiki](https://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Lordvessel):

> Most bonfires can be warped from, but only a few can be warped to.
> The warp locations must also be rested at to be made available.
>
> Warp Locations
> The Lordvessel can only teleport you to these bonfires:
>
> - Firelink Shrine
> - Alter of Sunlight
> - Chamber of the Princess (Gwynevere)
> - Anor Londo
> - Darkmoon Tomb (Anor Londo)
> - Alter of the Gravelord (Gravelord Nito's Tomb)
> - Daughter of Chaos (Queelag's Domain)
> - Stone or Everlasting Dragon (Ash Lake)
> - Undead Parish (Above Andre of Astora)
> - The Abyss
> - Depths
> - Tomb of the Giants
> - The Duke's Archives
> - Crystal Cave
> - Sanctuary Garden*
> - Oolacile Sanctuary*
> - Oolacile Township*
> - Chasm of the Abyss* (Oolacile Township Dungeon)
>
> `*` = Artorias of the Abyss [DLC] only.

Comment: wow that's not very many I wanted to warp to the demon ruins one guess its just not available... that sucks thanks though :)

Comment: @NathanTaylor The bonfire in the queelag's domain is probably the closest to the demon ruins.

Comment: @5pike, I think there might be a minor error in your answer. I believe it is possible to warp to the 'depth' without the 'artorias of the abyss' dlc.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but I believe most of the bonfires you could teleport to correspond to an area where you can join one of the the covenants.

Comment: @ColinD - I think they mean the Depths, where you fight Manus, Father of the Abyss. You can only get to these Depths when you have the DLC

Comment: @5pike, I think they made the bonfire warpable with the release of patch 1.06. The depths bonfire is not related to the DLC at all. Maybe the 'Abyss' should have the * and not the depths (manus is in the abyss). check out this wiki page http://darksouls.wikidot.com/bonfires

Comment: the abyss is the four kings bonfire, its the only way in and out of that area, it is not part of the artorias dlc and as such is labeled correctly.